# Has_Many_Through Failing To Push a Many to a Through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, has-many-through

I'm trying to set up a has_many_through relationship where a User can have a cart with an item. I can add carts to the user (`chip.carts << chips_cart`) but I can't push items into my carts (`chips_cart << coffee`).

I get `NoMethodError: undefined method` <<' for #<Cart id: 5, user_id: nil>`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :carts
    has_many :items, through: :carts
end
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :items
end
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :carts
    has_many :users, through: :carts
end

chip = User.create(username: "Chip")
chips_cart = Cart.create
socks = Item.create(item: "socks", price: 5.00)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Hubert you have a pluralization error:

```
belongs_to :cart # not :carts
```

The name of `belongs_to/has_one` assocations should always be singular.

And you don't need to use the shovel operator `<<` in the first place:

```
chip = User.create(username: "Chip")
chips_cart = chip.carts.create
socks = chips_cart.items.create(item: "socks", price: 5.00)
```

Individual records don't respond to `<<`. Which is why you are getting `NoMethodError: undefined method <<' for #<Cart id: 5, user_id: nil>`. If you want to use the shovel operator you need to do `chips_cart.items << socks` instead of `chips_cart << socks`.

#### Oh sweet syntactic sugar

If you really wanted to be able to do `chips_cart << socks` you could implement the `<<` method:

```
class Cart < ApplicationRecord
  # ...
  def <<(item)
     items << item
  end
end
```

Thats because the shovel operator like many operators in Ruby is really just syntactic sugar for a method call.

Comment: Thank you. I wound up using `chips_cart.items << socks` before I saw your answer. But since you expanded upon it, I'm going to go back and try it the second way you suggested to get a better understanding (and make it sweeter ;).

Answer (score 0):

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :cart
  ...
end
```

Comment: So I should drop the has_many_through for Item? Is that because each row in the Cart table will have one user?

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.